# Linear Algebra: Squared A is equal to the identity - is the following statement correct?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, proof-explanation

The question, which we should proof as being correct, is as follows:

"Let $A$ be an element of the 2x2 matrices over the real numbers with $A^2 = I$.
Then $A^3 + A^2 - A - I = 0$."

Why?

I thought maybe rewriting would help, canceling $A^2$ and $I$, but then I'm still left with $A^3 - A = 0$. Or $A(A^2 - 1) = 0$. Maybe someone could help.

Comment: Hint:  $A^3=AA^2$

Comment: Since $A^2=I$ you can simplify the other equation to $A(A^2-I)=0$

Comment: Be careful, $A^3 - A = A(A^2 - I)$ not $A(A^2 - 1)$.

Comment: If you add dollar signs around mathematical expressions when writing a post you are most of the way to achieving proper formatting; in this case it was all you needed (click the edit button to see what I mean). This time I've done it for you, but for next time, see https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation .

Comment: Thank you; It's such a stupid mistake to make thinking 1 and not the identity. Then it cancels to the zero matrix and I'm left with A*0 and I'm done, right?.
Also thanking for the formatting, I thought I saved the notation post, but in haste I couldn't find it; thanks for the reminder.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: if you can write $A^2 = I$, what can you say about $A^3 = A \cdot A^2$?